# What does this Pascal syntax mean

Tags: syntax, pascal

Here's this code:

```
for i:= 1 to n 
do Write(a[i]:6:2);
Writeln;
```

For loop outputs data from array..

Please, help - What does `:6:2` in `Write()` mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Write

Answer (score 4):

It's output formatting. This means use 6 digits for output with 2 decimal positions

Comment: 6 characters (icluding decimal separator).

Comment: but what if it's just :2 instead of :6:2 ??

Comment: @Dr - It will output all, the argument is the minimum number of characters to output.

Answer (score 0):

this will format your output in case you have a number/decimal in a. If i remember correctly, in your case, the 2 means the max number of decimal places below 0 and the 6 the maximum digits printed for numbers above 0.

HTH
Dominik

Comment: 6 the entire lenght of the output for that variable, and 2 the number of decimals. So 1.9876543 will be printed as '  1.99'.

Comment: In this example it would be 'ss1.99', where the ss represents two leading spaces. Rudy was correct. The spaces in the quotes he wrote didn't come through in the quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

The spec x:n:m means a field width of n and m decimal places. It will be formatted as a real.  If x=17.8 then x:6:2 comes out as " 17.80". Note that it is one leading space and that it is right justified. If m is 0 then no decimal point and no trailing digits. If you have x:n as the format you get scientific notation in a field width of n.

Also, n and m can be integer variables, so the field widths and decimal points can be changed during execution.